# file_put_contents failed the open stream doesn't work on localhost

Tags: php, localhost, file-put-contents

My PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php
$name=$_POST["name"];
$image=$_POST["image"];
$decodedImage= base64_decode("$image");
$link="192.168.1.34:80/kullanici/profil/";
$link=trim($link);

//file_put_contents("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\kullanici\\profil\\".$name.".JPG",$decodedImage);
file_put_contents($link.$name.".JPG",$decodedImage);
?>
```

If I use the commanded line the function works, but when I use the path `192.168.1.34:80/kullanici/profil` it gives me this error:

```
file_put_contents(192.168.1.34:80/kullanici/profil/ad.JPG): failed to
open stream: Invalid argument in
```

Comment: I think you're missing the end of the error message. Invalid argument in... what?

Comment: Maybe a file permission issue?

Comment: all error message this: <b>Warning</b>:  file_put_contents(192.168.1.34:80/kullanici/profil/ad.JPG): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\kullanici\resimkaydet.php</b> on line
<b>8</b>
<br />

Comment: What permission, how can i give a permission?

Comment: You cannot save a file using the http protocol. How should that work?

Comment: Watch the first 2.30 minutes, i copied code there and he can upload image: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMnQJKtmOd4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Your answer is very likely to be in the question linked above, especially part 5 : `allow_url_fopen`